# Deep comparison of object types

Tags: python, object, types

How to compare object types including subtypes? For example:

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3]
lst2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

`lst1` is a list of integers and `lst2` is a list of strings, so they are not equal. Another example:

```
dct1 = {'a': [1, 2, 3]}
dct2 = {'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

`dct1` and `dct2` are equal because both have keys as strings and values as lists of integers.

EDIT: For simplicity, we work with JSON-friendly types like dictionaries, lists, integers etc. We don't consider mixed subtypes like a list of integers and strings or a dictionary with different key/value types `{'x': [1, 'b'], 2: (2, 'c')}` and go only the two first levels deep. Answers with more general solutions are highly welcome.

Comment: Other than in, say, Haskell, in Python the type of elements isn't part of or a parameter of the type of container types. A `list` is just a `list`, not a "List of <something>". While the type hints (together with the [`typing`  module](https://docs.python.org/library/typing.html)) allow you to specify values restricted in both, container type and element type, and `mypy` allows to check them _statically_, I don't know whether Python supports to compare the _dynamic_ "deep" types of two compound values in any reasonable way.

Comment: Also, you'd have to further specify what you consider part of the "type": Are `[1, "2"]` and `["1", 2]` of the same type? What about lists of different lengths? Do the same rules apply to lists and tuples?

Comment: @das-g We don't consider such mixed types.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```py
def same_same(l1,l2):
  return([type(x) for x in l1]==[type(x) for x in l2])
```

So, to explain:

The function basically creates a new list of the types within `l1`, and vice versa for `l2`. It then compares them and returns `True` or `False`.

Note: Only works on lists.